# R - maximum position of a character in string

Tags: r

I have a list of strings which is like:

```
This - is - a test
```

i'd like to get the string `a test` from it.
My idea is to get the maximum position of "-" and then start a substring from that position. However am unable to accomplish this. Any help?

Comment: Do you need to get the position? Or just the text after the final '-'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use sub.

```
sub(".*-", "", x)
```

or

```
sub(".*-\\s*", "", x)
```

- `.*-` matches all the characters greedily upto the last hyphen.
- `\\s*` matches zero or more white-space characters.
- So by replacing all the matched chars with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way would be to use `strsplit` and `tail`:

```
lapply(strsplit(x, "-"), tail, 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] " a test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a string and you want all the matching position for a particular substring, you need to use `gregexpr`. In this case

```
tail(gregexpr("-",x,fixed = T)[[1]],1)
```

will give the last matching index, after which you can use `substr` to get your intended sub string.

If you want all the matches then remove the `tail` call.

HTH